# When I copy an API response to a js file in vscode, it puts everything in double quotes

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

In chrome devtools, when I hover over the preview of a response from a REST API call and click 'copy value', then I paste that value in a json file, it looks as I expect. When I paste that value in a js file, it does not look like I expect. What this is 'supposed' to look like may be irrelevant, I NEED it to look like test-file.json for it to work in my tests. I do not see a prettier rc config file.

Ex) test-file.json

```
  {
      type: 'mover',
      id: 888,
      organization_id: null
  }
```

Ex) test-file.js

```
  {
      "type": "mover",
      "id: 888,
      "organization_id: null
  }
```

I do not want prettier or vscode to put the key in my key value pair in double quotes. It should have no quotes. This doesn't work unless I painstakingly manually edit it.

My settings json looks like this:

```
{
    "redhat.telemetry.enabled": true,
    //"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    //    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    //},
    "[typescript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "[json]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features"
    },
    "git.confirmSync": false,
    "git.ignoreRebaseWarning": true,
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": false,
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {

        "bash": {
            "path": "bash",
            "icon": "terminal-bash"
        },
        "zsh": {
            "path": "zsh"
        },
        "fish": {
            "path": "fish"
        },
        "tmux": {
            "path": "tmux",
            "icon": "terminal-tmux"
        },
        "pwsh": {
            "path": "pwsh",
            "icon": "terminal-powershell"
        }
    },
    "html.completion.attributeDefaultValue": "empty",
}
```

My eslintrc.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: ['../../.eslintrc', 'next', 'plugin:cypress/recommended'],
  parserOptions: {
    warnOnUnsupportedTypeScriptVersion: false,
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: ['./cypress/**/*/*.{tsx,ts,js,jsx}'],
      rules: {
        'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': [
          'error',
          { devDependencies: true },
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

In Preferences/Settings I have:
Javascript Preferences: Quote Style to "auto"
Typescript preferences: Quote Style to "auto"
I tried setting Editor: Auto Closing Quotes to never

My coworker can copy and paste values from REST responses all day and he does not have to manually edit anything. What in his settings is different?

Comment: Keys in JSON files are always quoted, see https://www.json.org/json-en.html. The example you show for your test-file.json is most likely a pretty-printing artifact and would be invalid JSON as-is. test-file.js however looks like perfectly valid JSON (and JS, for that matter).

Comment: I need my key value pairs NOT to be in quotes for my cypress tests to work. The strings can be in single quotes but there needs to not be double quotes anywhere. If the test-file json is pretty-printing, the point is that I need my test-file.js to pretty print in the exact same way

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like VS Code thinks you are editing JSON.  You can manually set the type of file using the menu:

[image]

See how in the bottom right mine says Plain Text?  Yours likely says JSON.  Click that to open the menu you see at the top and then search for Javascript.  That should fix it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's always displayed Javascript so that's not the answer, though I wish it was